# check if array member exist

Tags: c#, arrays

All,

Consider following piece of code:

```
string message = "abc;def;ghi";
string[] msgs = message.Split(';');
string temp = msg[2] ? msg[2] : "Failed";
```

Message variable is coming from the server and has different length. I need to parse it so that if the value does not exist, result should be "Failed".

Is there an easy way to do that?

Right now this construct gives comppiler error: "Cannot convert string to bool".

Thank you.

[EDIT]

I guess some people read this letter by letter. ;-)
I need to check if an arbitrary element of the "msg" array exist, not just msg[2].
I can have something like:

```
string message = "abc;def";
str[] msg = message.Split( ';' );
string temp = msg[3] ? msg[3] : "Failed";
```

in the next message processing.

[/EDIT]

Comment: In `x ? y : z` the expression `x` *must* evaluate to a `bool`-type, just as it does in `if (x) { .. }`. That is what the compiler error is saying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you wanted:

```
string temp = msgs.Length > 2 ? msgs[2] : "Failed";
```

---

Edit:

For checking any element, the same thing works:

```
int index = 42;
string temp = msgs.Length > index ? msgs[index] : "Failed";
```

Comment: Not really. If I want to check whether the n-th element of the array exist it won't help.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Javascript, C# does not allow you to use arbitrary expressions as booleans.

You're trying to write

```
msg.Length >= 3 ? msg[2] : "Failed"
```

Comment: Also, unlike JavaScript (since it was brought up for comparison), `arr[i]`, where `i` is out of bounds, doesn't simply result in `undefined` :)

Comment: Sorry I corrected the question. What I meant to ask is: check existense of an n-th element in the array.